# How to get full hierarcy of files on google drive using google Api V3 C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, hierarchy, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm writing a sort of launcher application and using google disk to store files for my application. The launcher should use metadata of files from google disk for checking the integrity of files.

So, I'm using C# and Google.API (Google.Api.Drive.V3) to get metadata from a public link on google drive. I have service account, which has access to a folder, i have the JSON with its credentials, and I've given required access for google drive for a specific folder i need. Basically, I want to get a path that looks like (AllMods/modName/SomeSubfolder/Filename.dll).

So far, I've been able to get a file list and folder list.

```
       static string[] Scopes = new string[] {
            DriveService.Scope.Drive,
            DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
            DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata
     };

   public static List<string[]> getGoogleDiskModInfo(List<string> modList)
        {
            string folderid = "1EPjALeLqG9dT3c6YGup30u6dcmxVhsSB"; //public folder id
            List<string[]> fileInfo = new List<string[]>(); 

            GoogleCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                    .CreateScoped(Scopes);
            }

            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "servauth"
            });

            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ListRequest listFolderRequest = service.Files.List();
            listFolderRequest.PageSize = 1000;
            listFolderRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, md5Checksum, size, parents)";
            listFolderRequest.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> folders = listFolderRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            string[,] arrayFolders = IListToArray(folders, null, false);
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ListRequest listFileRequest = service.Files.List();
            listFileRequest.PageSize = 1000;
            listFileRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, md5Checksum, size, parents)";
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listFileRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            int count1 = folders.Count();
            int count2 = files.Count();
            string[,] arrayFiles = IListToArray(files, folders, true);
```

After that, I'm doing a recursive search for files from "IList files" by their Parents[0] and searching a folder in "IList folders" with corresponding id to Parents[0] until Parents is a null. (I'm calling that function in IListToArray, where i basically rewrite the data i need from IList To Array, so the search later would've been faster)

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Makes recursive search, and updates the string if parent is found.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file">file to search</param>
        /// <param name="files">IList of all folders with their respective meta</param>
        /// <param name="s">resulting path</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File RecursiveSearch (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file, IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files, ref string s)
        {
            if (file.Parents!=null)
            {
                string parentId = file.Parents[0];
                foreach (var potentialDirectory in files)
                {
                    if (potentialDirectory.Id == parentId)
                    {
                        s += "\\" + potentialDirectory.Name;
                        file = RecursiveSearch(potentialDirectory, files, ref s);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }   
            return file;
        }
```

My question and problems all following

1. For some reason, folders contained in the IList Folders are the first parents from the IList files. (There are also a lot of duplicate names (not id's) like DATA, can it cause any problems?" And, for some reason, Folder.Count gives the same amount as the IList files.Count. Basically, i'm getting only some subfolders of folder that i have given an access to, and not all of them.
2. How does listFolderRequest.Q = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'" works? Is there a lis t of mimeTypes somewhere? Maby the search is the problem that causes it.  I don't quite understand how to use searches in these situations. And i don't understand why that gives only some subfolders.
3. Is it possible to make the request for all files including folders and subfolders? Something including "*.*" idk.

Thanks in advance

upd 1.

```
public static string[,] IListToArray(IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> iList, IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> folderList,  bool fullPath)
            {
                string[,] arrayFiles = new string[iList.Count, 6];
                int i = 0;

                foreach (var file in iList)
                {
                    if( fullPath)
                    {
                    string s = "";
                    RecursiveSearch(file, folderList, ref s);
                    arrayFiles[i, 0] = file.Name;
                    }
                    else arrayFiles[i, 0] = file.Name;

                    arrayFiles[i, 1] = file.Size.ToString();
                    arrayFiles[i, 2] = file.Id;
                    arrayFiles[i, 3] = file.Md5Checksum;
                    arrayFiles[i, 4] = file.WebContentLink;
                    if (file.Parents != null) arrayFiles[i, 5] = file.Parents[0];
                    else arrayFiles[i, 5] = null;
                    i++;
                }
                return arrayFiles;
            }
```

And the recursive search method.

````
/// <summary>
        /// Makes recursive search, and updates the string if parent is found.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file">file to search</param>
        /// <param name="files">IList of all folders with their respective meta</param>
        /// <param name="s">resulting path</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File RecursiveSearch (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file, IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files, ref string s)
        {
            if (file.Parents!=null)
            {
                string parentId = file.Parents[0];
                foreach (var potentialDirectory in files)
                {
                    if (potentialDirectory.Id == parentId)
                    {
                        s += "\\" + potentialDirectory.Name;
                        file = RecursiveSearch(potentialDirectory, files, ref s);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }   
            return file;
        }
    ```
````

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't actually need to "build" the full folder structure, but only return a list of files and folders that are children (or grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc.) of a specific folder. Is that correct?

Comment: I might be wrong on calling that full hierarchy. Is there a better way to rephrase that question? 
I have a list of files on google drive, and i want to get all of their parents. That's why I'm also trying to get all folders, to recursively search for corresponding Parents id's.
So, if i have the file "file.cfg" i want to get "mainfolder/modname/DATA/file.cfg".

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to accomplish. You are talking about a specific folder (even setting the `folderid`) but then you don't use it again in your code. You want to retrieve all files (and folders, which, in Drive, are just a specific type of files) in your Drive, or just from a specific folder?

Comment: Oh. I can see why you're confused.  I want to retrieve ALL files which are accessible to the service account.

Basically, i need an array of such paths to use it as a kind of database later.  I will just sort those if they have the folder i need in the path i want to get.  Right now my problem is that i don't get all the folders accessible to the service account, for some reason i get only the parent of files from that line ("IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listFileRequest.Execute()
                .Files;")

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to get an array of string[], each having a name of a mod folder they are in, a download link, hash, and their size.

Comment: And for each file, I want to get all the "folders' above.

Comment: Could you share the function `IListToArray`?

Comment: I've updated a post and added IListToArray.

Comment: I think this could be a problem about the service account not having access to all the files you think it should have access to. The requests you're making should retrieve all files you have access to. Could you double-check that? Also, as far as I can see, you're not recursively calling `Files.list` with each successive `pageToken`, so if the list is over 1000, it will only retrieve those 1000. Finally, I don't see a reason to make two different calls to retrieve (1) all files and (2) only folders. You could just retrieve all files. Is this to minimize the amount of later iterations?